# NASM assembly number to base conversion

Tags: assembly, nasm, radix

I have what seems to me to be a fairly straightforward project. Ask user for a number between 0-255 and base between 2-9. And output in that  base. I plan on simply doing a usual division algorithm and getting the remainders, pushing onto the stack, and poping back off to get the reverse order to output back to the user. However after inserting a few print debugging statements I am getting very strange output for the remainder

`; Run using nasm -f elf -g -F stabs proj4.asm
;                gcc -o proj4 proj4.o -m32
; To execute type proj4`


`%macro SAVE_REGS 0
    push eax
    push ecx
    push edx
%endmacro`


`%macro RESTORE_REGS 0
    pop edx
    pop ecx
    pop eax
%endmacro`


`%macro CALL_PUTS 1
    push %1
    call puts 
    add esp, 4
%endmacro`


`%macro CALL_SCANF 2
    push %1
    push %2 
    call scanf
    add esp, 8 
%endmacro`


`%macro CALL_PRINTF1 1
    push %1         ;The address of the string to print 
    call printf
    add esp, 4
%endmacro`


`%macro CALL_PRINTF2 2
    push %1         ;The formatted string with a %char place holder
    push %2         ;The item to place into the place holder 
    call printf
    add esp, 8 
%endmacro`


`SECTION .data`


`prmptNumMsg: db "Enter a number between 0 and 255: ", 0
prmptBaseMsg: db "Enter a base between 2 and 9: ", 0
remShow: db 'The the remainder is: %d', 10, 0
numShow: db 'The number is %d', 10, 0
baseShow: db 'The base is %d', 10, 0
printed: db 'Looped in division method', 10, 0
poped: db 'Looped in pop method',10, 0 
ansShow: db '8d', 10, 0

numFormat db '%d', 0 
stringFormat db '%s', 0`


`SECTION .bss
numVal resd 1
baseVal resd 1
ans resd 9
i resd 1
n resd 1
j resd 1`

`SECTION .text
    global main`


`extern puts 
extern scanf
extern printf`


`main:`


    `push ebp    ; Set up stack frame for debugger
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi
    ;Everything before this is boilerplate`


`getInt:
    CALL_PRINTF1 prmptNumMsg`


    `;push numVal
    ;push numFormat
    ;call scanf
    ;add esp, 8
    CALL_SCANF numVal, numFormat`


    `mov eax, dword[numVal]
    mov ebx, dword 0                ;check below 0
    cmp eax, ebx
    jb getInt
    mov eax, dword[numVal]
    mov ebx, dword 255          ;check above 255 
    cmp eax , ebx
    ja getInt 
    ;VALID INTEGER PAST THIS POINT`


`getBase:
    CALL_PRINTF1 prmptBaseMsg

    CALL_SCANF baseVal, numFormat`


    `mov eax, dword[baseVal]
    mov ebx, dword 0
    cmp eax, ebx
    jb getBase
    mov eax, dword[baseVal]
    mov ebx, dword 9
    cmp eax, ebx
    ja getBase`


`;END GETBASE 
    ;VALID BASE NUMBER PAST THIS POINT
    mov eax, dword[numVal]
    mov [n], eax    ;set n to the current number value 
    CALL_PRINTF2 eax, numShow
    mov eax, dword 0
    mov [i], eax 
    mov eax, dword[baseVal]
    CALL_PRINTF2 eax, baseShow
doDivision:
    ;CALL_PRINTF1 printed
    xor edx, edx 
    mov eax, dword[n]
    mov ebx, dword[baseVal]
    div ebx     ;edx = remainder eax = quotient
    mov [n], eax ;save quotient

    CALL_PRINTF2 eax, numShow 
    CALL_PRINTF2 edx, remShow`


    `;push edx   ;save remainder on stack to pop in reverse order later 
    ;mov [n], eax  ;move quotient to eax`


    `mov ebx, dword[i]
    inc ebx
    mov [i], ebx ;i++`


    `;mov eax, [i]
    mov ecx, dword 8
    cmp ebx, ecx
    jb doDivision 
;END DO DIVISION`

`end:`


    `;Everything after this is boilerplate
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret`

When the program is run my output is as follows 

`Enter a number between 0 and 255: 105
Enter a base between 2 and 9: 4
The number is 105
The base is 4
The number is 26
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 6
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 1
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 0
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 0
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 0
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 0
The the remainder is: 13144896
The number is 0
The the remainder is: 13144896`

I want it to loop 8 times which is correct, the quotient of each div operation is correct, however I'm getting crazy numbers for the remainder which would be held in edx. I don't understand whats causing this.

Comment: Change the order of these two lines and see what happens. Then figure out why. `CALL_PRINTF2 eax, numShow` and `CALL_PRINTF2 edx, remShow` after the division.

Comment: What? **You mean you have to compute the remainder before you can print it?** Whoever heard of such nonsense. Print the uninitialized value first, then try and compute... something... Good catch, write it up in an answer form with a bit of explanation and the OP should accept.

Comment: Further hint: `printf` returns a value.  Where does it put it?  Incidentally, the problem looks [very familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657061/nasm-program-assembly-language/26686793#26686793) (though the question being asked is more specific).

Answer (score -1):

When you call a routine (for example: printf), there are rules that govern how this works.  For example, do you put the parameters on the stack?  Or pass them in registers?  Do you push parameters from left to right?  Or right to left?  Does the caller pop the parameters off the stack?  Or does the callee?  Where will return values be located?

Most importantly for your question, does the callee need to make sure that all registers will have the same value when it returns?  Or can it overwrite some of them?

The answer to these questions are called the "calling conventions" (or sometimes ABI).  And there isn't just one answer.  For example cdecl, pascal, and fastcall are all common calling conventions on the x86, and they all answer these questions in slightly different ways.

I believe you will find that printf is cdecl.  With that in mind, you might check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl.  That should help you understand what is happening to edx in this example.

Comment: The OP provided specific code with a simple specific problem that needed to be addressed. While the content of your answer is generally true, it does nothing to address the issue with the order of `CALL_PRINTF2` calls made in the code. Moreover, sending the OP off chasing general information when specific help is needed may inject more confusion into the issue rather than making it better. Sometimes discretion is the better part of valor in choosing whether to leave a comment or leave an answer.