# NASM program Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, nasm

Program : enter an integer in base 10 from 0 to 255 and will change the number into base n (where n is from 2 to 9).

I know how to convert from base 10 to 2. but not base 10 to any other base.
Any links or example might be sufficient to get me started.

Comment: It's elementary mathematics. Divide by the base in a loop, and write down the remainders in reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to provide the translation to the original answer, and mindful about giving a man a fish and feeding him for a day, the following is the `NASM` translation. **Note:** this is 32-bit code as in original:

```
; build and link (32-bit on x86_64)
;
; nasm -f elf -o baseconvert_32.o baseconvert_32.asm
; ld -m elf_i386 -o baseconvert_32 baseconvert_32.o

section .data

    base10  db 255
    newbase db 7
    result times 8 db 0
    newline db 10

section .text
                global _start

        _start:
                mov     edi, result         ; offset in result string

                xor     ax, ax              ; zero/clear ax register
                mov     al, [base10]        ; at start, current remainder = whole value
                mov     bl, [newbase]

        loop:
                div     bl                  ; divide current remainder by new base
                mov     [edi], ah
                cmp     al, 0               ; is the quotient zero?
                je      printchar           ; if it is we are done
                xor     ah, ah
                inc     edi                 ; move offset in result string (note digits
                jmp     loop                ; of answer are stored in reverse order)

        printchar:
                add    byte [edi], 48       ; add ascii '0' to digit to get printable char
                mov     eax, 4              ; linux sys_write
                mov     ebx, 1              ; stdout
                mov     ecx, edi            ; point to current digit
                mov     edx, 1              ; number of chars to print
                int     0x80                ; syscall
                dec     edi                 ; point to next digit
                cmp     edi, result         ; are we past the final digit?
                jge     printchar           ; if not, keep printing to stdout

                ; print newline
                mov     eax, 4
                mov     ebx, 1
                mov     ecx, newline
                mov     edx, 1
                int     0x80

                xor     ebx, ebx            ; set zero exit code
                mov     eax, 1              ; set syscall number to __NR_exit 1 (0x1 hex)
                int     0x80                ; call kernel (syscall 32-bit)
```

**output:**

```
$ ./baseconvert_32
513
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not NASM, it's gas, but the following code works for me on Linux.  Perhaps you or some friendly stackoverflower can [translate it into NASM](http://xathrya.web.id/blog/2013/08/20/comparison-of-intel-nasm-and-att-gas-assembler-format/).

Compile on linux with `gcc -nostdlib -g -o filename filename.s`.

You can change 255 and 7 to the dividend and base you want.

If you aren't running Linux/Unix, the system calls are unlikely to work.

The [algorithm](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/CompSci/Introduction/frombase10.htm) is fairly straightforward.

```
.data

base10:
    .byte 255
newbase:
    .byte 7
result:
    .byte 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 # since dividend <=255 and divisor >=2
                          # 8 digits in the new base is enough
newline:
    .byte 10 

.text

.global _start
_start:

    movl $result, %edi  # offset in result string

    xorw %ax, %ax
    movb base10, %al    # at start, current remainder = whole value
    movb newbase, %bl   

loop:
    divb %bl            # divide current remainder by new base
    movb %ah, (%edi)
    cmpb $0, %al        # is the quotient zero?
    je printchar        # if it is we are done
    xorb %ah, %ah
    incl %edi           # move offset in result string (note 
    jmp loop            # digits of answer are stored in reverse
                        # order)

printchar:

    addl $48, (%edi)    # add ascii '0' to digit to get printable char
    movl $4, %eax       # linux sys_write
    movl $1, %ebx       # stdout
    movl %edi, %ecx     # point to current digit
    movl $1, %edx       # one char to print
    int $0x80           # syscall
    decl %edi           # point to next digit
    cmpl $result, %edi  # are we past the final digit?
    jge printchar       # if we aren't keep going

    # print a newline
    movl $4, %eax       
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $newline, %ecx
    movl $1, %edx
    int $0x80

    # finish nicely
    movl $0, %ebx   
    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

Comment: Yep, giving the OP full working code will teach him anything.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: SO is an educational site?